# Apparently I can increase my bounty, how?

Tags: support, bounty

According to the description of bounties, I can increase my bounty as long as I increase it by double the amount that was originally added, this is what the description says:

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the
>   minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on
>   the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and
>   so on).

So how do I add these additional bounties? Do I need to wait for a certain amount of time or is there a button hidden somewhere that I've missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There can only be one active bounty on a question at a time.

Once the bounty period is over and the bounty awarded, you can start **another** bounty.

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for details.