# increasing the amount of a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Is there a way to increase the amount of an existing bounty?  I am thinking about the situation in which someone posts a bounty but does not get a reply after a few days.  It seems like the only alternative now is to wait 7 days for the first bounty to expire, then lose all the points you devoted to the bounty even though no one responded, then double the bounty and go into another 7 day wait period.

If there is a way to increase the bounty, can it be done in a way that ensures that all references to the bounty show the full (increased) amount?  It would be a waste if the higher amount were not propagated to all references in the site.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260775/62576. See also [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065) and search for *raise*.

Comment: Patience Grasshopper.  It has only been active 2 days.  If it was an easy question it likely would have gotten an answer for free.  The question also seems complex (and with 2-3 strict criteria!) - anyone interested in answering may have to do their own research and testing.

Comment: This feature request does not provide enough details. If a user starts a bounty at 50 and then increases it to 100, what would be the total rep cost to the bounty giver, for instance?

Comment: Most of my bounty experiences tend to not attract answers until it gets close to the end.  I would say that anything you do after 2 days is probably an overreaction.

Answer (score 15):

> *"Is there a way to increase the amount of an existing bounty?"*

None, that I know about.

> *"It seems like the only alternative now is to wait 7 days for the first bounty to expire, then lose all the points you devoted to the bounty even though no one responded, then double the bounty and go into another 7 day wait period."*

Yes, you'll actually **have to increase** the bounty amount, and wait that time, if you're marking a question as bounty a second time.

During the running bounty it's not possible to change the amount of offered rep, since it was actually taken by the engine, as soon you applied it (not as you state *"**then** lose all the points"*).

I think that's by design, and a feature request may come out pretty worthless. Here's a cite from **[How does the bounty system work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/186472)**:

> **Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired?**
>   **Can I raise my bounty?**
>
> You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time. Moreover, any user may have at most 3 concurrent bounties at a time.
>
> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, you will have to double the amount each time (or more). That is, if your first bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200 and so on. If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like (or as long as you have the rep). This doubling applies only to bounties by the same user on the same question.

Comment: Yes, I know the points are taken immediately when you post the bounty.  This would be acceptable for many reasons.  However, it is not acceptable to leave the bounty poster unable to increase the amount of the bounty.  This is a flaw in the SO application logic that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @CodeMed _"However, it is not acceptable to leave the bounty poster unable to increase the amount of the bounty."_ Why? You'll need to decide what it's worth of your rep to possibly get a concise answer beforehand, and then it's running with that value. Any increasing of the offered rep during a running bounty, would be unfair against any users that gave an answer under the original conditions, wouldn't it. Also bounties are much overrated IMHO. I'm rarely looking on featured questions matching my favorite tags. Usually these are hitting some exotic cases just matching side ways with may favs.

Comment: If someone provides an answer before a bounty is increased, that would mean that their answer is not sufficient, so they would not be rewarded the bounty anyway, unless they improved their answer.  The system would award the full (increased) bounty to whomever has their answer finally selected. My question was about situations where there is no response.  And yes, there are SO users who cruise the bounty offerings.  Bounties provide an opportunity for an asker to get a larger amount of attention from potential answerers when needed, and are thus an important part of the SO ecosystem.

Comment: Wouldn't a fair compromise be to allow bounties to be increased only if a question has no answers?