# Bounty wasn't large enough - no way to increase it? What could be done?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I recently had to deal with an ASP.NET web forms app to help improve its performance.  It's been tricky due to the extensive use of update panels.  I got to a point where I could not figure out the issue so I posted a question: [Performance deteriorating after async postback - scrolling becomes horrendous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359065/performance-deteriorating-after-async-postback-scrolling-becomes-horrendous) then I added a bounty.  I initially offered 100...but maybe I was being cheap for something that required more work.

I did not see a way to edit the bounty; I assume you cannot once you've submitted it?  Has the idea ever been tossed around to allow a larger bounty once one is posted?  I just don't know what other information I can add that would help me in any way.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JonH You can add a second, larger bounty after this one expires if you get no results

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - True but it may be that I actually lose out on this one...assume no one helps with the original and repost now for an additional 200 - that means I'm out 300 instead of 200.

Comment: My first suggestion: Have patience. You've still got five days on that bounty- It might well be more than enough to get you a decent answer. If it _does_ fail to net you an answer, barring a feature for extending and increasing a bounty being added in the next week, you _can_ at least set another one if needed. Not quite what you're looking for, I know.

Comment: @Kendra - true enough thank you.

Comment: I'm also asking what other content I could ask in the question to get an answer so I am not sure why this was closed?

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it's been discussed before: [increasing the amount of a bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285373/increasing-the-amount-of-a-bounty)

The idea was not popular. Which brings me to the other part of your question... **What can you do when no one's paying attention to your bounty?**

1. **Wait.** You're not "paying for work"; you're paying for advertising. And the longer your bounty runs, the better placement you get on the list of bountied questions. When you *first* offer your bounty, you're at the bottom of the list; as the days go by, your question gets closer and closer to the top.
2. **Edit.** Presumably you're not sitting on your hands; if the problem was important enough for you to offer a bounty, you're probably still searching far and wide for a solution, trying different approaches, etc... **So write 'em up!** If nothing else, knowing what *doesn't* work might save potential answerers time spent going down dead-ends themselves, leaving them more time to find a solution that *does* work.
3. **Re-bounty.** If your bounty expires without a solution, you can offer another, larger bounty. Since you're primarily paying for advertising, it may actually be worth your while to *always* start with a small bounty, as this allows you the chance at the maximum amount of exposure for the reputation you're giving up. The *best* part of this is that it allows you to award increasingly-large bounties for increasingly-complete answers...

I suspect that #3 is one of the reasons for folks' dislike of the previous suggestion to allow increasing bounty values; some problems are hard to crack, and folks have traditionally wanted to withhold the full bounty from anything less than a complete answer when they put a lot of rep on the line. Allowing answerers to bite off pieces and work collaboratively on solutions can be less stressful and more productive for all involved, and the current system does actually encourage this to a certain degree (albeit in a manner that is completely non-obvious to an awful lot of folks offering bounties).

Comment: You're right I'll add more content tomorrow

Comment: that's a fairly good advice [imNSho](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=bounties&sort=offered)