# Increase a bounty value after set

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Usually, I'm starting a bounty when I didn't get enough attention on my question. After starting with 50 bounty, I realized that, I should increase it. I guess, there should be a single time way for the bounty owner to reset the original bounty. For consistency, one can't decrease it, but they can increase it.

Would it be helpful to pay more attention after setting the bounty?

Comment: Close-voters: The OP is asking for the possibility to increase a bounty's value after it's been set. The question isn't that unclear.

Comment: And when this is reopened it's a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285373/458741

Comment: @Ben, thanks, but my question is different in a way that, one can increase the bounty amount right after he set and it will be possible to increase it for few hours. I don't want to wait for 7 days to reassign a new bounty. But I can add up in the existing bounty. As I am adding more points there would be no issue to increase it. But yes, there should be some conditions match to help protect it for any bad things.

Comment: @Hemang perhaps if you made a more concrete feature-request? Maybe something like: "I propose that a bounty amount may be increased by the bounty poster within an hour of setting it"... If you're lucky, if you've not long set a bounty and really do want to up it from 50 to 100 - a mod might (if you flag as "other" and explain you want the bounty refunded so you can offer a different bounty amount) agree with you.

Comment: That other question hasn't been answered well @Hemang, more as a support question instead of a feature request. The actual request looks very similar though, a way to increase the bounty after it's been set.